# CXF endpoint setting: how to specify that wsdl and schema files are in a 'resources' folder?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have CXF configuration file with such tag:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="..." implementor="..." address="..." wsdlLocation="RESOURCES/someWsdl.wsdl">    
...   
   <jaxws:schemaLocations>   
      <jaxws:schemaLocation>RESOURCES/types.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
       <jaxws:schemaLocation>RESOURCES/schema.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
   </jaxws:schemaLocations>
...
</jaxws:endpoint>.
```

Q: How to specify that **someWsdl.wsdl**, **types.xsd** and **schema.xsd** are in a **resources** folder:

```
PROJECT_HOME\src\main\resources
```

Comment: Some additional context would be helpful. Are you building your project with Maven?

Comment: ...with Maven... posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="..." implementor="..." address="..." wsdlLocation="classpath:someWsdl.wsdl">    
...   
   <jaxws:schemaLocations>   
      <jaxws:schemaLocation>classpath:types.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
      <jaxws:schemaLocation>classpath:schema.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
   </jaxws:schemaLocations>
...
```

.